# How to extract time stamp in a column using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset(Excel) has one single column, but there is too much information. I would like to convert it into tabular format based on the time stamp. I want to convert it into columns like: Time, Name, URL. I am trying to use Python Pandas to achieve this.

I am looking at datasets like this:

```
6/10/2017  8:40:34 AM

James

URL:.....(multiple rows)

6/10/2017 8:45:34 AM

Jenny

URL:....
```

How can I do this using Python Pandas?

Comment: Are you saying that there are multiple rows with the value of `URL` or that there are multiple triplets of `Time`, `Name`, and `URL`?

Comment: Can we assume that rows in dataset can be divided into groups that match order like Datetime, Name, Url (1 or more)?

Comment: The multiple rows in url means that I cannot extract data based on their location. So I am thinking get times stamp first and then use time stamp location to get other variables like Name and URL.

Comment: Hi Ben Wurth, your understanding is right..

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use reshape provided the values are in precise order

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.values,(len(df)//3,3)))
df.columns = ['Time', 'Name', 'URL']

    Time                    Name    URL
0   6/10/2017 8:40:34 AM    James   URL:.....(multi rows)
1   6/10/2017 8:45:34 AM    Jenny   URL:....
```

Edit: Here is another approach

1. Extract time using pd.to_datetime
2. Extract URL using str.contains(URL)
3. Everything else goes to Name
4. Groupby every three row to fill NaNs and drop duplicates.

   df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], errors = 'coerce')

   df.loc[df['col'].str.contains('URL'), 'URL'] = df['col']

   df['Name'] = df[(df['Time'].isnull() & df['URL'].isnull())].col

   df.drop('col', axis = 1).groupby(df.index//3).ffill().bfill().drop_duplicates()

You get

```
    Time                URL                     Name
0   2017-06-10 08:40:34 URL:.....(multi rows)   James
3   2017-06-10 08:45:34 URL:....                Jenny
```

Comment: Hi I cannot use location to index the data. ,Multi rows mean that time is not always in columns like 3, 6, 9.....I am confused about how to find those time stamp...I plan to find them first and based on time data location to further indexing...

Comment: Thank you very much! I am working on it using your method. Hope I could solve this problem.

Comment: Hi, it is not working very well...I did not find a way to deal with NaT to split time column...

Comment: Its difficult to think of solution beyond this if I am not able to reproduce the errors:(

Answer (score 0):

here's an approach that could help.

```
#create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['6/10/2017 08:40:34 AM', '6/10/2017 08:45:34 AM'], 'name':['James', 'Jenny'], 'url':['www.yahoo.com', 'www.google.com']})

# Set the index of the dataframe to time
indexed_df = df.set_index('time')

# review the original dataframe
df
Out[11]: 
    name                   time             url
0  James  6/10/2017 08:40:34 AM   www.yahoo.com
1  Jenny  6/10/2017 08:45:34 AM  www.google.com

# check the newly indexed dataframe
indexed_df
Out[12]: 
                        name             url
time                                        
6/10/2017 08:40:34 AM  James   www.yahoo.com
6/10/2017 08:45:34 AM  Jenny  www.google.com
```

I hope this helps. This was taken from this doc https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

Comment: The problem is my dataset is not just two records and there are hundred....